# Why am I getting null body values on my api request?

Tags: .net-core, react-redux, axios

Context:

- It's a .Net Core app
- Using React, Redux, and Axios which finally makes the request.

Axios call:

```js
// At this point I do have values on my request
// { "param1": 2021, "param2": "where the sidewalk ends" }
console.log(myRequest);

axios.post('api/myPath/create', myRequest, options)
    .then(function (result) {
        ...
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        ...
    });
```

Api controller:

```cs
namespace myNamespaceApi
{
    [Route("api/myPath/create")]
    [ApiController]
    public class MyCreateController : .....
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize(Policy = ShouldBeCertainRole)]
        public async Task<MyApiOperationResult<MyCreateResponseViewModel>> Post([FromBody] MyCreateRequestViewModel request)
        {
            try
            {
                .....
                // at this point my request comes with null values
                // { "param1": null, "param2": null }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               ....
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So it is making the call, but not reaching the method with the values.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is in your then() call? did you return the response as json? `then(response => response.json())` ? or whatever format you need the data in?

Comment: The problem is not the response, the problem is when gets to the api method it comes with no values, in the C# code. Javascript code it does have a value just before making the call.

Comment: Alright, I solved it. In my case, it worked by changing the view model class properties to:
public class MyRequestViewModel
{
 public int Param1 { get; set; }

 public string Param2 { get; set; }
}
Instead of:
public class MyRequestViewModel
{
 public int Param1 { get; private set; }

 public string Param2 { get; private set; }
}

So I removed private.